# Ios 8: Determine the destination app when my app goes to the background?

Tags: ios, iphone, openurl, abpersonviewcontroller

I override my app's openURL-method to know when we're about to leave the app from an `ABPersonViewController`, the reason being that that class doesn't notify its delegate on all of the actions it presents to the user. If it did everything would be fine.

This worked flawlessly in iOS 7, but when trying this in iOS 8.1 it turns out that the `ABPersonViewController` doesn't call `openURL` for all its actions anymore. For instance, tapping a phone number gets me to the phone app without calling `openURL`. Tapping the SMS bubble on the other hand *will* call `openURL`.

When tapping the facebook profile entry (with the URL "fb://profile/1234567890") the log says that "Launch Services" doesn't have a registered handler for the scheme "fb". So I'm assuming that calls to Launch Services have replaced the calls to openURL. I can't find out much more about it other than that it's "a private API".

Is there a way to detect these calls? Or, is it possible to override handlers for known schemes like "tel" and "mailto" internally for my app? I basically just need to know when we're leaving the app and **where we're going**.

Comment: This would make a great enhancement request at Apple's bug reporter site. Right now, I'm afraid that what you see is what you get (i.e. not much).